# Where to put "more"?

Tags: word-usage

1) You sound more like a native speaker.

2) You sound like a native speaker more.

I know the first one is correct, but can I use the second one?

Comment: Generally it is safest to put an adverb just after the verb. The second one is not wrong, but I wouldn't consider it a natural phrasing at all.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, the "more" being after sounds quite odd. While technically not grammatically correct, I would definitely not use it in conversation.

Very rarely will English speakers speak like this, but usually with a shorter word than "native speaker"